# Does Tomcat 4 server supports Struts 2.16?

Tags: tomcat, struts

Does tomcat version 4 supports Struts 2.16 version?
Existing application is build using struts 1 and needs to be migrated to Struts 2.
Will that be possible without changing Tomcat version?

Comment: *shrug* Why would you bother doing a complete application re-write but not bother upgrading your server? Makes no sense.

Comment: Tomcat 4.1 was last released in 2009 which about the same time that Struts 2.1.6 was first released.  I would give it a shot but as @DaveNewton says this makes almost no sense as you're dealing with 8 to 10 year old software at this point.